# How to convert a table (xlsx or csv) to a list of strings in Python?

Tags: python, excel

I have an xlsx file with only one column. Each cell contains some text, one word, or a few sentences. Let's say like this one in the picture

[image: 1].

Or like

```
dog
cat
pig
apple for people
nice to meet you
```

I want to convert this file to the following view in code:

```
var = ["dog",
"cat",
"pig",
"apple for people",
"nice to meet you"]
```

Is it possible to do it with Python? I don't need the index of the rows either, just convert table to a list with strings. I searched for the answer but the solutions I found don't meet my needs. I don't need output like:

`[['This is the first line', 'Line1'], ['This is the second line', 'Line2']`

or

```
1 dog
2 cat
3 pig.
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a .csv file called foo.csv with only one column, then:

```
import csv

with open('foo.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    result = [str(row[0]) for row in reader]
    print(result)
```

Comment: When I use this code with my file I'm getting an error - IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Try deleting the `[0]` after row i.e. `[str(row) for row in reader] `

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas

```
import pandas as pd

list = []

df = pd.read_csv(foo.csv)

df_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(df)

list = df_dataframe['yourcolumn']
```